# How do I create a linear regression model for a file that has about 500 columns as y variables? Working with Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, linear-regression

This code manually selects a column from the y table and then joins it to the X table. The program then performs linear regression. Any idea how to do this for every single column from the y table?

```
yDF = pd.read_csv('ytable.csv')
yDF.drop('Dates', axis = 1, inplace = True)
XDF = pd.read_csv('Xtable.csv')
ycolumnDF = yDF.iloc[:,0].to_frame()
regressionDF = pd.concat([XDF,ycolumnDF], axis=1)

X = regressionDF.iloc[:,1:20]
y = regressionDF.iloc[:,20:].squeeze()

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X,y)
cf = lm.coef_
print(cf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regress multiple y's on the same X's at the same time. Something like this should work

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df_X = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['x1','x2','x3'], data = np.random.normal(size = (10,3)))
df_y = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['y1','y2'], data = np.random.normal(size = (10,2)))
X = df_X.iloc[:,:]
y = df_y.iloc[:,:]
lm = LinearRegression().fit(X,y)
print(lm.coef_)
```

produces

```
[[ 0.16115884  0.08471495  0.39169592]
 [-0.51929011  0.29160846 -0.62106353]]
```

The first row here (`[ 0.16115884  0.08471495  0.39169592]`) are the regression coefs of `y1` on xs and the second are the regression coefs of `y2` on xs.

Comment: Thank you! My goal is to add conditions to the regression (for example, if coefficients are negative, delete those X columns and perform regression again with the remaining columns), so that's why I'm thinking I should do it one y variable at a time

Comment: if you are going to manually tweak X for each column of y, I am not sure what exactly is your question -- sounds like you need to do it manually. or in a `for` loop

Comment: Yeah I think I need to use a for loop, just wan't sure how to approach it using .iloc to read each y column.

Comment: `for n in range(df_y.columns): y = df_y.iloc[:,n]`